# Please help me work out this error, regarding the use of a HTTPService to connect Flex4 & Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, flex4, httpservice

I have a HTTPService in Flash Builder 4, that is defined as follows:

```
<s:HTTPService id="getUserDetails" url="http://localhost:3000/users/getDetails" method="GET"/>
```

It gets called as follows:

```
getUserDetails.send({'user[username]': calleeInput.text});
```

Here is a screenshot of the network monitor, showing that the parameter is being sent correctly (it is 'kirsty'):

[alt text http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/7513/screenshot20100430at548.png](http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/7513/screenshot20100430at548.png)

Here is the Ruby on Rails method that it's connected to:

```
def getDetails    
    @user = User.find_by_username(:username)
    render :xml => @user
end
```

When I run it, I get the following error output in the console:

> Processing UsersController#list (for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2010-04-30 17:48:03) [GET]   User Load (1.1ms)   SELECT *
>   FROM "users"  Completed in 30ms (View:
>   16, DB: 1) | 200 OK
>   [http://localhost/users/list]
>
> Processing UsersController#getDetails
>   (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-04-30 17:48:13)
>   [GET]   Parameters:
>   {"user"=>{"username"=>"kirsty"}}
>   User Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM
>   "users" WHERE ("users"."username" =
>   '--- :username ') LIMIT 1
>
> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing
>   template users/getDetails.erb in view
>   path app/views):
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:36:in
>   `getDetails'
>
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in`
>   service'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in
>   `run'
>
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in`
>   start_thread'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in
>   `start'
>
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in`
>   start_thread'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in
>   `start'
>
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in`
>   each'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in
>   `start'
>
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in`
>   start'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in
>   `start'
>
> Rendering rescues/layout
>   (internal_server_error)

I'm not sure if the error is being caused by bad code in the getDetails Ruby on Rails method? I'm new to RoR, and I think I remember reading somewhere that every method should have a view. I'm just using this method to get info into the Flex 4 app, do I still need to make a view for it? Is that what's causing the error? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a few days now! Thanks.

EDIT:

As per Toby Hede's suggestion, I changed the HTTPService as follows, adding the .xml:

```
<s:HTTPService id="getUserDetails" url="http://localhost:3000/users/getDetails.xml" method="GET"/>
```

Now I am getting the following error:

```
Processing ApplicationController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-04-30 23:32:29) [GET]
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"kirsty"}}

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/users/getDetails.xml" with {:method=>:get}):
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'

Rendering rescues/layout (not_found)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Rails is looking for a getDetails.erb.html file in the corresponding view folder. You need to make a request to the url with a ".xml" on the end to tell the server that you want an XML response. Otherwise it defaults to HTML, resulting in this error.

Comment: How would I make the call to a ".xml"? Sorry, I'm still learning and don't know very much! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I meant change the url to have .xml on the end: "http://localhost:3000/users/getDetails.xml"

Comment: Ah haha can't believe I didn't work that out. I made the change, and am getting a different error now. I'll edit it into the original message. Is there a better way for me to post updated code/errors than that? Thanks again!